# Python: Reemplazar string en lista si string comienza con "X"

Tags: python, string, str-replace

Tengo una lista muy larga de direcciones IP (almacenadas como strings), cada una correspondiente a una ubicación física (edificio) conocida, y necesito reemplazar cada dirección IP de la lista por el nombre de su ubicación correspondiente.

La lista es de 400 elementos, pero el formato es el siguiente:

```
ip_list = ['10.0.0.10','10.0.1.12','10.0.0.5','10.0.1.25']
```

Por ejemplo, sabemos de antemano que las direcciones IP `10.0.0.5` a `10.0.0.255` corresponden a la ubicación "X" y las direcciones IP `10.0.1.5` a `10.0.1.255` corresponden a la ubicación "Y". Lo que necesito es reemplazar cada IP de esos rangos con `"Edificio X"` o `"Edificio Y"` en la lista.

Intenté lo siguiente pero no funcionó

```
for ip in ip_list:
  if ip.startswith('10.0.0'):
    ip.replace(ip,'Location X')
```

También intenté hacerlo con list comprehension sin resultados (de hecho esto borró todos los elementos de la lista)

```
ip_list = [ip.replace(ip, 'Location X') for ip in ip_list if ip.startswith('10.0.0')]
```

Mi conocimiento de Python es rudimentario, por lo que toda ayuda se aprecia, saludos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Estás en el sitio en español, así que todas las preguntas y respuestas deben escribirse en español. Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/441712/edit) tu pregunta y traduce todo, **incluyendo el título**

Comment: ¿Qué sale si haces `print(type(ip_list[0]))` ?

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de como es esa lista de ips por favor?

Comment: @abulafia ```<class 'str'>```
@DanteS. añadido ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el primer caso está haciendo el procedimiento más o menos bien, pero no estas guardando el resultado en ningún lado. Además, si necesitas remplazar toda la cadena, ya para eso sale mejor guardar la nueva cadena directo en el resultado.

Asumiendo que solo tienes dos rangos de IP, el código quedaría:

```
result = []
for ip in ip_list:
    if ip.startswith('10.0.0'):
        result.append('Location X')
    else:
        result.append('Location Y')
```

Usando comprensión de listas (gracias @DanteS)

```
result = ['Location X' if x.startswith('10.0.0') else 'Location Y' for x in ip_list]
```

O también se puede usar [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) y su respectivo callback lambda:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: 'Location X' if x.startswith('10.0.0') else 'Location Y', ip_list))
```

Comment: También podrías usar comprensión de listas así: `['Location X' if x.startswith('10.0.0') else 'Location Y' for x in ip_list]`

Answer (score 0):

con el replace se crea una substring (variable temporal), no se modifica la string original. Si no guardas esa string en algún sitio, por ejemplo en una nueva variable o nueva lista (aquí te muestro ambos), si no lo guardas entonces la vas a perder.

```
new_iplist = []

for i in ip_list:
    if i.startswith("10.0.0."):
        new_i = i.replace(i,"Location X")
        new_iplist.append(new_i)
    else:
        new_i = i.replace(i,"Location X")
        new_iplist.append(new_i)

print(len(ip_list))
print(len(new_iplist))
new_iplist
```

Alternativamente, puedes ir almacenando simplemente creando nuevos items en una nueva lista:

```
new_iplist = []

for i in ip_list:
    if i.startswith("10.0.0."):
        new_iplist.append("Location X")
    else:
        new_iplist.append("Location Y")

print(len(ip_list))
print(len(new_iplist))
new_iplist
```

Espero que te sirva